# Read/capture packets larger than 65535 bytes with scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I am reading USBPcap files created in Wireshark with large, isochronous packets up to 494439 bytes. I am then trying to parse the packets in python with scapy. Unfortunately, scapy 2.4.3 defaults to ignoring bytes past the 65535th byte for packets greater than 65535 bytes.

Is there a way to read packets larger than 65535 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to instruct scapy to read packets larger than 65535 bytes, you must read packets one at a time off the many pcap reading generators found in [scapy.utils](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.utils.html) API. Specifically, the following classes within `scapy.utils` support reading large packets from a pcap or pcapng file:

1. `class scapy.utils.PcapReader(filename)`
2. `class scapy.utils.PcapNgReader(filename)`
3. `class scapy.utils.RawPcapReader(filename)`
4. `class scapy.utils.RawPcapNgReader(filename)`

Note that `scapy.utils.rdpcap(filename, count=- 1)` does not support this functionality.

My solution:

```
from scapy.all import *

packet_reader = RawPcapNgReader('my_pcapng_file.pcapng')

while True:
    try:
        # created my own usb_packet class to parse packet header on __init__
        p = usb_packet(packet_reader.read_packet(size=500000)) # read packet up to 500 kB large
        if p.filter(): # filter packets based on usb_packet custom filter method
            print(len(p.hex_str), len(p.data_packets)) # do stuff to the filtered packets
    except EOFError:
        break
```

For capturing packets via `sniff` or similar, one might set the buffer size via `class scapy.config.Conf.bufsize` which defaults to 65536 to allow a 65535 byte packet to be captured (see [docs](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.config.html#scapy.config.Conf)). For pragmatic programming, one may set this configuration when reading pcaps as well rather than maintaining the `size` argument wherever `read_packet()` is called on a generator.

[An interesting note](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/why-the-maximum-ip-packet-size-is-65535/td-p/1897269): This default appears to be due to IPv4 packet structure in which the packet length is represented by a 16 bit number. In other words, the largest packet this header value can depict is `1111111111111111` bytes, or 2^16=65536. Counting from zero, we have the largest IPv4 packet being 65535 bytes. For USB, as in my case, larger packets are possible.

Comment: You can set `conf.bufsize`

Comment: @Cukic0d Thanks for the tip! I have updated the answer to reflect this configuration setting.